# Защита Connection String

Tags: c#, .net, безопасность

Вопрос сложный, но хотелось бы услышать аргументированные ответы. 
Суть проблемы: Connection String - способ хранения, как обойтись без нее(если таково возможно) и подключаться к базе данных (платформа .NET). Такие варианты, как app.config(web.config) с шифрованием секции, реестр и сам исходный код - **не предлагать**. WCF и EntityFramework тоже хранят ее в открытом виде. Как с этой строкой справляются в корпоративном ПО?

P.S. База данных - на удаленном хосте mySql. Может стоит как-то получать эту строку через сайт по защищенному каналу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я не уверен, что вам это нужно. Connection String, как правило, лежит в `app.config`/`web.config`. Конфиг не доступен по сети, локально права на его чтение можно ограничить.

Comment: А поподробнее про ограничение прав на чтение? Спасибо.

Comment: Что-то типа этого: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419/ru и http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754/ru

Правда, опять таки, не совсем понятно, зачем это нужно - защищайте сервер, а не Connection String.

Comment: Спасибо, изучу. Смысл защищать сервер, если ключик к нему лежит в открытом виде в этом ConnectionString? Вот как раз и защищаю от любопытных)Интересно, как с этим делом обстоят дела в Java.
Единственная вещь - ConnectionString, которая не позволяет начать продавать мне софт. Хотел сделать авторизацию на GRANT'ax, но хостом разрешен только один пользователь БД, а на другой хост переехать не получиться.

Comment: Защищайте веб-сервер, в том числе.

> Интересно, как с этим делом обстоят дела в Java.
Неужели вы думаете, что можно положить данные как-то так, чтобы их могло прочитать только приложение и никто другой? Кстати, в этом случае можно просто отреверсить приложение и прочитать данные. Все, что может быть сделано приложением, может быть сделано и человеком с помощью подходящих инструментов.

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы это было так, но в текущих реалиях хотелось бы усложнить получения ключика от сервера.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю исходной проблемы, на самом деле. параметры для подключения к базе знает только веб-приложение. Его клиенты напрямую подключиться к базе не смогут. Клиентов, при необходимости, можно авторизовать на веб-приложении.

Comment: Суть проблемы, что у нас десктоп-приложение и оно подключается к бд, а там в ConnectionString: URL, где база находится и логин\пароль, заходи и верти, что хочу и как хочу.

Comment: Не работайте напрямую с базой со стороны десктопного приложения, подключайтесь к серверу через API, пусть доступ к базе имеет только сервер.

Как бы вы не защитили Connection String, его можно будет прочитать из памяти работающего приложения.